# fdisk doesn't create partitions with the requested size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, scripts, windows, fdisk

I am trying to write a script to automate the task of partitions creation for ubuntu alongside windows, and for creating partitions I am using `fdisk`, but the problem is that the Windows OS has already created 3 primary partitions (I guess), and I want to make two more partitions, one as boot partition and one as root, so when I am trying to make these two partitions, with or without using the script, I face the problem that I can't make my root partition bigger than boot partition, considering the fact, that I would like to create my boot partition first and whatever is left of the disk should be used as root partition, assume that I am having 15GBs of free space on my disk, I would like to create my boot partition with the size of 512MB and the rest should be used for root partition without the need to enter the size.
This is the script that I use to create the partitions:

```
create_boot_partition() {
    echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "Creating the Boot Partition"
  sudo fdisk $disk_location <<EOF
  n



  +512MB
  w
EOF

}

create_root_partition() {
    echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "Creating root Partition"
  sudo fdisk $disk_location <<EOF
  n
    
    
    
    
  w
EOF

}

disk_location=/dev/sda
create_boot_partition
sudo partprobe $disk_location
create_root_partition
sudo partprobe $disk_location
```

Screenshot below are provided for better understanding, first one shows partition table before running the script and the second one shows partition table after running the script.

[image: Before running the script]

[image: After running the script]

I would like to have a solution, to be safe (Risk of data loss on Windows side is not acceptable) and be able to implement it using a script.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So you did create two partitions (extended, and the sda5), as expected, just not the types you expected.  Hard to tell what's going on with the fdisk input containing so many spaces (defaults). Maybe sfdisk would be better?

Comment: `(Risk of data loss on Windows side is not acceptable)` means that you have to manage proper backups before you take any other action. This is a must, anything could happen when you test the script for the first time or any disruption like a power cut. Remind, `fdisk` only manipulates the partition table, formatting the partition (LVM, ext4, etc) must be done by other tools. If it's only a single machine, it wouldn't be worth the time to develop a script, just doing manual partitioning with gparted or the 'something else`-option during install would be much faster.

Comment: @mook765 It is not a single machine, it is something that is being used often, that is why I am trying to script it, and the formating would be done while I am going to install the Ubuntu, but for data loss, consider what you suggested is done, then what should be done, to achieve it.

Comment: @ubfan1, even without the script, if I do it manually I get the same result.

Comment: Then you can include your manual (cut and paste) of what you are doing in fdisk.  Select primary vs extended, etc. that is hard to guess from the blank defaults. You should be making three parttiions, extended, /boot, and / .

Comment: Would it be possible that you convert from a MBR to a GPT partition table first? This way you would get rid of the 4 primary partition limitation. But you need UEFI BIOS to boot then.

Comment: Still I would second @ubfan1 : please don't use `fdisk` like this, you really should work with `sfdisk` because with `fdisk` you probably will not have consistent results after you got it working.

Comment: Your Windows is installed in BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. So either very old Windows which should be obsoleted, or incorrect install that really should be UEFI. But conversion from MBR to gpt will normally totally erase drive, so good backups required.

Comment: To install Ubuntu on the partitions created in advance you have to use the `something else`-option anyway to  format these partitions and define their mountpoints. So I don't see any advantage of creating these partitions in advance by running a script. The script would be a big deal, it must be able to handle different conditions ( every machine might be different) regarding partition table (GPT or msdos), MBR limitations, extended partitions and so on. What should the script do if other partitions would have to be resized or moved, a difficult task...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is not possible in this way: Your harddisk has a MBR partitioning table (MBR = "master boot record"), visible in the fdisk output as "Disklabel type: dos".

This allows either for up to four primary partitions, or up to three primary partitions plus one extended partition. The extended partition can then link again to the next extended partition and so on.

So when your Windows installation already has created three primary partitions, you can only add one more primary partition or an extended partition.

I haven't been using MBR partition scheme for a while now, but back when I used it, it was advisable to have the boot partition as primary partition. Might have changed by now.

So you have several options:

- add extended partition and then two or more partitions for boot and Linux root
- add extended partition and move one of the Windows partitions so that it becomes part of the extended stuff
- convert the whole partitioning scheme to GPT, then you don't have to take care about primary and extended partitions.